# Is it possible to download and transfer PSN games to PSVita from PC?

Tags: psn, ps-vita

Is it possible to download PSN games (PSVita, Vita-compatible PSP games and minis) via PC software (i.e. Media Go) and then connect Vita with the PC and transfer Vita-compatible games (either by using Media Go, Vita Content Manager Assistant or some other way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do so because PS-Vita games can only purchasable via a PS3 with a valid account. You can only transfer PSN games via a PS3 (this restriction is not applicable for media contents, videos, music etc.)

See here http://mediago.sony.com/enu/features/devices for all the devices that supports MediaGo to transfer content, and PS Vita is not listed.

Comment: I am not sure that's correct - I believe I did purchase a PSP game from PS Store, downloaded it and transfered to my PSP using Media Go. You can enter the Store and log in to your account in similar manner as on PSP. I wonder if it is also possible with Vita.

Comment: See here http://goo.gl/wqgpX for all the devices that supports MediaGo to transfer content, and PS Vita is not listed.

Comment: Ok, it seems Media Go does not work with Vita, but you can access PS-Store using it. It just won't work with Vita games. Now the question is - is the Content Manager Assistant or any other PC software compatible with Vita and PSN games?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a way. Sony might integrate PSN game transferring support in MediaGo in future.

Comment: OK, if there is no other input I guess you can update your answer and I will accept it. Tough luck for the non-WiFi non-PS3 Vita owners.

Comment: @sarmackie Well, you can always use a USB dongle to bridge a wired network connection from PC to a wireless one, like what Nintendo was offering when the DS came out.

Comment: Yeah, don't know how could I forgot about such a simple workaround :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can login and purchase games from PC, but it just adds them to a download list - then you can transfer from the PS3 after they are downloaded, or go direct to vita.